# Как задетектить программное нажатие клавиш?

Tags: java, windows, клавиатура, эмулятор

Какие способы есть для обнаружения программного нажатия клавиш в моём приложении?
Решаемая проблема: Защита от ботов.

Comment: Опишите проблему, которую вы хотите решить с помощью такого обнаружения. Формулировка очень похожа на проблему XY

Comment: @ГерманБорисов добавил проблему, которую хочу решить с помощью такого обнаружения

Comment: К сожалению, между вашим прикладным ПО и клавиатурой всегда находится программная прослойка в виде Windows. Так что, на самом деле, все нажатия клавиш, которые видит ваша программа - программные. К тому же есть виртуальные клавиатуры для людей с ограниченными возможностями. Предлагаю как альтернативу рассмотреть возможность анализа частоты и продолжительности серий нажатий. Человек, например, точно не может ежедневно по 12 часов долбить по клавишам с частотой сто нажатий в минуту.

Comment: Просто я слышал для устройств (проф. геймерские клавиатуры и мышки), которые имеют вой собственный USB-драйвер (и набор ПО для автоматизации) обнаружение эмуляции невозможно, поэтому и подумал что значит для стандартных устройств есть какой-то способ обнаружить эмуляцию нажатия.

Comment: Некотрые игр сканирует запущенные на компе приложения, отслеживает использование API функций для эмуляции работы мыши и клавиатуры и т.д. 
Ну вот например: https://kibor-bot.com/stat/bypassprotection.php
"На сегодняшний день все автокликеры так или иначе используют API функции эмуляции клавиатуры и мыши. ...
AvtoK первый автокликер поддерживающий эмуляцию действий с мышью и клавиатурой на уровне железа и не использует API функций.За счет этого его работа невидима для защит. "


т.е. всё таки есть способы обнаружения программного нажатия?

Comment: Текст по ссылке больше похож на выхлоп маркетолога, чем на технические подробности

Comment: Сам нашёл ответ.
@ГерманБорисов похоже вы не разбираетесь в теме и подвержены эффекту Даннинга — Крюгера
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82_%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9A%D1%80%D1%8E%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Windows предоставляет механизм уровня ядра, который позволяет отличить реальное нажатие клавиши от симулируемого.** Рассмотрим, как
>   можно использовать этот механизм для обнаружения кликеров.
>
> Прежде всего, мы должны перехватить событие нажатия клавиши на низком
>   уровне. В этом нам поможет WinAPI подпрограмма `SetWindowsHookEx`.
>   Принцип её работы похож на функцию AutoIt `HotKeySet` – она
>   устанавливает обработчик различных событий ОС. Первый параметр
>   `SetWindowsHookEx` определяет тип перехватываемых событий. В нашем
>   случае он должен быть равен `WH_KEYBOARD_LL`.
>
> Теперь мы должны реализовать функцию-обработчик события. Она получает
>   входным параметром структуру типа `KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT`, которая содержит
>   полную информацию о перехваченном событии. У этой структуры есть поле
>   `flags`. Если в нём присутствует флаг (то есть бит в определённой
>   позиции) `LLKHF_INJECTED`, перехваченное нажатие клавиши было
>   симулировано WinAPI подпрограммой `SendInput` или `keybd_event`. Если
>   флага `LLKHF_INJECTED` нет, источником события является клавиатура.
>   Подменить поле `flags` структуры `KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT` достаточно сложно,
>   поскольку оно выставляется на уровне ядра ОС.

https://ellysh.gitbook.io/video-game-bots-ru/clickerbots/protection

Как видим на примере AutoIt, способы обнаружить программное нажатие клавиш - существуют, конечно это не защитит от очень продвинутых ботов-кликеров, но от большинства простых вполне, а продвинутых останется вычислять методами статистики или даже машинного обучения.